# Laravel extends - only send parameter when condition

Tags: laravel, extends, laravel-blade

I want to check for `$house->category`.
Depending on the category i want to send parameters with the `@extends()` functions.

I can't get it to work. When I use something like:

```
@if($house->category == 1)
    @extends('templates.main')
@else
    @extends('templates.main', ['logo' => 'img/logo/logo_red_white_text.png', 'favicon' => 'img/favicon/favicon_red.ico'])
@endif
```

The template is injected twice.

Answer (score 0):

use "@include" instead of extends, and if it's being injected two times you can prevent that by handling that logic on the controller, make a method "checkHouseCategory" or something like that, to check if $house->category == 1, then just send a boolean to the template.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you cannot pass parameters in `@extends` function.

What you can do is to move the view partial to separated file and then `@include` it in i.e. main file with the above condition. So this will looks like:

*Partial view with `@extends` I will name: example.blade.php*

Then in the main view partial:

```
@if($house->category == 1)
    @include('example')
@else
    @extends('example', ['logo' => 'img/logo/logo_red_white_text.png', 'favicon' => 'img/favicon/favicon_red.ico'])
@endif
```